# Using Zustand causes render loop (React)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, zustand

I'm trying to use zustand with immer middleware to create a global state for my React app (I'm using gatsby).
When I try to use the store I've created as mentioned below, I get the `Maximum update depth exceeded` error in the console

```js
import { create } from "zustand"
import { immer } from "zustand/middleware/immer"

import { minPriceOptionsResiSale } from "../SearchFilter/filterOptions"

const initialState = {
  minPrice: minPriceOptionsResiSale[0],
  minPriceOptions: minPriceOptionsResiSale,
}

export const useResidentialStore = create(
  immer(set => ({
    ...initialState,
    setMinPrice: minPrice =>
      set(state => {
        state.minPrice = minPrice
      }),
    reset: () => set(_ => ({ ...initialState }), true),
  }))
)
```

this is how I've used it

```
  const {
    minPrice,
    minPriceOptions,
    setMinPrice,
  } = useResidentialStore(state => ({
    minPrice: state.minPrice,
    minPriceOptions: state.minPriceOptions,
    setMinPrice: state.setMinPrice,
  }))
```

but when I access them like this,

`const minPrice = useResidentailStore(state => state.minPrice)`
there is no render loop. So, destructuring them from an array or object causes the issue.

Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's better not to spread the object like `set(_ => ({ ...initialState }), true)` when using immer (it already clones the input data); we also don't need to pass a function as the first argument, so the better code here would be `set(initialState, true)`
2. The returning value of `useResidentialStore` in here is an object which is a referential value, which means if any other value in the Zustand state changes for any reason, even if the updates don't touch our values, the memory locations update, so the component re-renders.
   To fix this particular issue, use `shallow` as the second input of `useResidentialStore`.
3. The infinite render loop is maybe because when the `minPrice` value changes, then the `minPriceOptions` changes, and that causes the component to re-render, maybe somehow the `minPriceOptions` updates again (not necessarily the value, but an update in the memory location also counts for the component to trigger a re-render) and based on the code you have, chances are that the component perceives it as an infinite render loop. So, if the value of `minPriceOptions` somehow depends on `minPrice`, they shouldn't be returned in one selector (need to use two separate selector hooks), and probably each selector should be used a separate component (if they depend on each other).